# Best way to freeze and application while the database is doing some heavy background work?

Tags: android, database, transactions

I have a background service that does some heavy lifting within a transaction once a day. If the user happens to start the app at this time, I want them to sit tight till it finishes (around 10 secs or so). What's the best way to do this across all activities? Check if the service is running in the "onResume" function of each activity? And how do we know when it's done? Local broadcasts I'm guessing...

Best practices anyone?

UPDATE: I've managed to stall "onResume" till my service is done. The problem is that the user just sees a blank screen till then. I've tried progressdialogs and regular dialogs while onResume is paused. But they all display only when onResume returns and that defeats the purpose. In other words, Progress dialog doesn't "show" immediately after "show()" is called :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local broadcasts is good.

Have your activities question the service if it is busy or not, and display an appropriate message to the user before finishing the activity.

Once the service is done, have it send an intent that it is finished.

Comment: Yeah, I've decided to just exit the screen if the user starts up the app when the service is busy! Unfortunately, a "Toast" message doesn't seem to work when I've called finish() :|

Answer (score 2):

I would have a '***I'm busy processing***' flag in the db.

And the app should check on start up, and then lock the app in a nice way, and then check say every x seconds to see the state of the flag. It could do this during normal processing so every action checks this flag locally and on the server before starting.

Seems like a simple way of locking. So you will have to take contention into account (multiple users setting and unsetting) possibly using a a semaphore type arangement.

Comment: Haven't studied semaphores yet, but I tried your suggestion. I did a "thread.sleep" in a while loop in the "onResume" method, but the screen went blank and never woke up :)

Comment: Got it to work :) . The only issue is that while the "onResume" function is sleeping, I can'g get a toast or a dialog message or progress dialog to show up - those come alive after onResume...well, resumes!

Answer (score 0):

use **AsyncTask** in your service to do heavy database work.

and use **Shared Preferences** to save a flag to notify other activities that work is on progress. When flag is true means Work in progress and when flag is false means Work has been done.

**Do something like this :**

```
 private class DatabaseWork extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {


 protected void onPreExecute ()
  {
      //Set SharedPref flag = trueto notify other activities that work has been started.
   }
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

      //Your database work
     return false;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     //if you want to show progress to user
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     //after complete your work set SharedPref flag = false to notify other activities that work has been finished.
 }
```

}

Now you can check SharedPref flag value on each activities onCreate or onResume event. If you found true then you can  show a progress dialog to tell user to wait.

Comment: I'm running the task in a service, so in "onResume", I check to see if it's running and if not, put it to sleep for a couple of seconds in a while loop. Only thing is, while the UI thread is sleeping, I'm not able to display a dialog or a Toast message. Those seem to show up AFTER the onResume has completed which kind of misses the point!

Comment: @Bhagwad - Don't sleep in `onResume`. Instead, design your lifecycle methods (`onCreate`, `onResume`, `onPause`, etc.) to work in one of two states, corresponding to whether the work is done.

Comment: The thing is, if my database is locked, then super.onResume throws an error. Since I have to call that any which way, I'm screwed unless I can delay execution till my database is lock free.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found was to create a "loading activity" that always loads up first and sends the user off to the main screen when it was safe to do so.